# I don't understand Google Chrome extensions. Please help. 

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to do something that seems like it should be fairly simple, but I can't get it to work.

All I want it to do is when the button in the popup is clicked I want to log the word "Hello" to the console. At the moment nothing happens. No error message. Just nothing.

Here is my manifest.jason file

```
{
    "name": "Content Script",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Experiments with content scripts.",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Here is my popup.html

```
<h1>Hello</h1>

<script>
function changeField() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {"code": "sayHello"});
    });
}
</script>

<button onclick="changeField();">Click</button>
```

Here is my contentscript.js

```
function sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello");
}


chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, response) {
        if(request.code == 'sayHello') {
            sayHello();
        }
    }
);
```

I've been reading the docs but they seem to skip over a lot of things. If someone could explain why this doesn't work I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Are you able to click the button in the popup? Also, which page's console are you checking?

Comment: your code seems fine,it should works theoretically

Comment: @Digital Plane Yes I click the button and nothing happens. I'm looking at the console by right-clicking on the popup's icon and clicking inspect popup.

Comment: @MrMisterMan Try invoking the console on the webpage (Press `F12`, or right-click `Inspect element`) and see if there are any logs. If that doesn't work, try it with wukong's solution.

Comment: @Digital Plane You are correct. I was inspecting the popup. The content script is technically being invoked on the webpage. I can see the logs now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't inject your `content script` to the page which `console` lives in.
Add `content_scripts` segment to your `manifest.json` file.

There is [a reference of manifest.json file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html) on chrome extension official site.

```
{
    "name": "Content Script",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Experiments with content scripts.",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts":[{
        "matches":["http://*/*"],
        "js":["content_script.js"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: @MrMisterMan I test it by myself,it works as expected,you can download  at http://hellohtml5.googlecode.com/files/extension_sample.zip. Your code is not modified.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Once I added the `content_scripts` field to the manifest file it was working. However I couldn't see this because I was inspecting the console of the popup, not the console of the page the content script was running on. D'oh! Thanks for your help.